# String split into 6 parts every character in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, split

I want to be able to split a string into 6 separate strings every character.

So for example IAMABADPROGRAMMER

would result in: IDA, APM, MRM, AOE, BGR, AR

Is there a haskell function to do this?

Thanks

Comment: So you want a function `String -> [String]` that groups every sixth character together?

Comment: the string is separated in multiples of 6. character 1 goes to string 1, character 2 to string 2 etc until character 6 has gone to string 6 then the next character 7 goes back to string 1 and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a function to do it already, but it can be written quite easily:

```hs
import Data.List (transpose)

chunk :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunk _ [] = []
chunk n xs = first : chunk n rest where (first, rest) = splitAt n xs

splitSkip :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitSkip n xs = transpose $ chunk n xs

main :: IO ()
main = print $ splitSkip 6 "IAMABADPROGRAMMER"
```

My first intuition was to generalize this to all lists, not just lists of `Char`s.  When you remember that the type `[String]` is the same as `[[Char]]`, you see that you end up with a 2D matrix of `Char`s, where if you went down each column going left-to-right, you would get the original list back.  Well, that's the same as transposing the matrix and going down each row top-to-bottom, which is the same as just splitting the original list into chunks of `n` elements first.  At this point, I had the solution, just worked backwards.  I wrote a quick function to chunk a list, then used the `transpose` function from `Data.List` to finish it off.

Comment: Also see `chunksOf` from the `split` package (included in the Haskell Platform), allowing you to write `splitSkip n = transpose . chunksOf n`.

Comment: @user2863323 As a challenge, try implementing your own `splitAt` and `transpose` (doesn't have to be efficient).  `splitAt` is pretty easy, but `transpose` should be a bit of a challenge (hint: `map`, `head`, `tail`)

Answer (score 2):

I was sure this could be done with list comprehensions and nothing beyond the basic functions in Prelude...

```
    groupNth :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
    groupNth n [] = []
    groupNth n xs = take n $ [ y | y <- everyNth xs ] : groupNth n (tail xs)
            where
            everyNth [] = []
            everyNth l@(y:ys) = y : everyNth (drop n l)
```

Seems to work and I think is more efficient than using transpose.

Comment: Not true on being more efficient, I put your code in with mine and ran it with `+RTS -s -RTS`, on 1 million ints (`[1..1000000]`), splitting into chunks of 1000, my answer ran in about 0.24 seconds, while yours ran in about 4.6 seconds.  That's a 20x speed difference.  The GC times and maximum memory residency were about the same, but mine used about twice as much heap space.  You can see full output here -> https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/6906826

Comment: Ah, can't beat empirical testing ;-)

Comment: Your comment simply made me curious as to which would actually be more efficient, and so I put them to the test.  I didn't think mine would be slower, but I've been wrong a lot before =)